# App resume incorrectly

Tags: android

I have a issue when work on resume feature:
Ex: I have 3 Activity `A`, `B`, `C`.

1. Build app to .apk file.
2. Install it from SDCard (using astro or other file manager
   application) -> go to Activity `A` -> `B` -> `C`
3. At activity `C`, press home device button -> app go to background.
4. At application screen of device, i click on icon app.

Actual result: go to Activity `A`

Expected result: resume to Activity `C`.

After step 4, I press the back button, and it goes to `C` -> `B` -> `A`. The app starts a new activity `A`, not resumes to `C`.

I searched from google but could not found the root cause. Please help me!

Mainifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.singlemode"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.singlemode.AActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.singlemode.BActivity"
       ></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.singlemode.CActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Below is the link example:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/m2hm2k1mvh8ryoo/ResumeError.zip

AActivity.java

```
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_activity);
    button.setText("Go to Activity B");
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AActivity.this, BActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

BActivity.java

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_activity);
    button.setText("Go to Activity C");
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(BActivity.this, CActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

CActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_activity);
    textView.setText("Activity C");
}
```

Comment: Show your Manifest file.

Comment: Check if you don't have `android:noHistory="true"` in your Manifest in activity C.

Comment: i just use default in mainfest file.

Comment: Please copy the code you use in order to start the activities. Thanks.